# How to use formatDateTime in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to format the pipeline trigger time in this format:

```
10-Mar-2021 08:31:59 AM
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
@formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM/PM')
```

However the date is coming out in this format:

```
'DD-3ON-YYYY 08:3I:SS A3/P3'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `formatDateTime` function uses the custom date format strings which you can see listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).  A detailed breakdown

```
dd - the day of the month from 01 to 31.  Note this is lower case and this format gives a leading 0.  Using d for no leading 0
MMM - the abbreviated name of the month, eg JAN, FEB, MAR.  Note this is upper case
yyyy - the year as a four-digit number.  Note this is lower case
hh - the hour using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.  Note this is lower case.  As you are using AM/PM it makes sense to have the 12-hour clock rather than 24 (ie 23:00 PM would not make sense).  Note this is lower case
mm - the minute from 00 to 50.  Note this is lower case
ss - the second from 00 to 50.  Note this is lower case
tt - the AM/PM designator.  Note this is lower case
```

So using this information, your code should be more like this:

```
@formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

I have test the expression using a Set Variable activity and got the following results:

[image: ADF result]

Answer (score -1):

```
EEE : Day ( Mon )
MMM : Month in words ( Dec )
MM : Day in Count ( 324 )
mm : Month ( 12 )
dd : Date ( 3 )
HH : Hours ( 12 )
mm : Minutes ( 50 )
ss : Seconds ( 34 )
yyyy: Year ( 2020 ) //both yyyy and YYYY are same
YYYY: Year ( 2020 )
zzz : GMT+05:30
aa : ( AM / PM )
```

Comment: **mm : Minutes ( 50 )
**mm : Month ( 12 )
Please fix this error. You're giving a wrong answer and 2) provide a link