# Azure Data factory not able to convert date format

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to get DAYID as string in format YYYYMMDD, however its not working correctly.

I have a timestamp field, I take first 10 characters and convert it into date (working correctly)

```
toDate(substring(EventTimestamp,1,10))
-- 2021-03-24
```

However when I try to convert to string using below expression, I;m getting wrong answer. I;m getting the Day as 83.

```
toString(toDate(substring(EventTimestamp,1,10)),'YYYYMMDD')
  --20210383
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date format characters are case-sensitive as per [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560903/how-to-use-formatdatetime-in-azure-data-factory/66562516#66562516), so use `yyyyMMdd` instead.

An example using `formatDateTime`:

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd')
```